# cannot set UIEdgeInsets of table View in swift 2.0 xcode 7 beta

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7-beta3

I am trying to set UIEdgetInsets of TableView in Xcode7 beta with swift 2.0
here is my code[image]

I keep getting this error while setting UIEdgeInsets
[image]

Comment: (Look up the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIEdgeInsets) and then) replace `CFloat` by `CGFloat` ...

Comment: didn't notice that thanks for the help

Comment: And in general: include the code, not a screenshot of the code, or in the future you will receive screenshots of answers instead of answers.

Answer (score 0):

UIEdgeInsets takes as arguments either 4 CGFloats or 4 ints, you have provided it with an unknown type CFloat and 3 ints hence swift doesn't have an initialiser for that. Adjusting CFloat to CGFloat should solve the problem